# Sympy diffgeom for Christoffel symbols

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to compute Christoffel symbols with Sympy Diffgeom.

```
from sympy import symbols, pi, sqrt, atan2, cos, sin
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem, Differential, TensorProduct, metric_to_Christoffel_2nd,metric_to_Christoffel_1st,twoform_to_matrix

# Define spherical coordinates
r, theta = symbols('r theta', nonnegative=True)

# Define the relation dictionary for transformations between Cartesian and spherical coordinates
relation_dict = {
    ('Car2D', 'polar'): [(x, y),
                       (sqrt(x**2 + y**2), atan2(y, x))],
    ('polar', 'Car2D'): [(r, theta),
                       (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))]
}

# Create a manifold, patch, and coordinate systems for spherical coordinates
m = Manifold('M', 2)
p = Patch('P', m)
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
Car2D = CoordSystem('Car2D', p, (x, y), relation_dict)
polar = CoordSystem('Sph', p, (r, theta), relation_dict)

# Define differentials for spherical coordinates
dr = polar.base_oneform(0)
dtheta = polar.base_oneform(1)

# Define the metric tensor
g = 1*TensorProduct(dr, dr) + r**2 * TensorProduct(dtheta, dtheta)
# Compute the Christoffel symbols
print(metric_to_Christoffel_2nd(g))

# Print the Christoffel symbols

twoform_to_matrix(g)
```

After defining all the parameters, I get the correct metric but all the Christoffel symbols are 0. Please find the code below.